RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
This is the Updated Code which I have change the Dimension, I have also got Some suggestion on this code about the error which i have posted above Now , but I didn't understand Properly, can you please explain it where I have to update in the code.
From Pytorch community --
This error points to the target used in nn.CrossEntropyLoss or nn.NLLLoss having an invalid shape.
Your code is unfortunately not executable, so it’s not trivial to copy/paste it to fix other issues.
From stackoverflow--
You need to focus, I previously told you to update the shape of fin_inten which you did. Now: you are throwing z_new into fin_inten which is a nn.Linear(2048,6) and right after into fin_e1 which is a nn.Linear(64,2). Your code is not consistent, you can't just throw random tensors into functions and hope for the best!
  class Classifier(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.MFB = MFB(512,768,True,256,64,0.1)
      self.fin_y_shape = torch.nn.Linear(768,512)
      self.fin_old = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin = torch.nn.Linear(16 * 768, 64)
      self.fin_inten = torch.nn.Linear(2048,6)
      self.fin_e1 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e2 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e3 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e4 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e5 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e6 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e7 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e8 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      self.fin_e9 = torch.nn.Linear(2048,2)
      # self.reduce_x = torch.nn.Linear(768, 512)
      # self.reduce_rag = torch.nn.Linear(768, 512)



      self.validation_step_outputs = []
      self.test_step_outputs = []


    def forward(self, x,y,rag):
        x_,y_,rag_ = x,y,rag
        print("x.shape", x.shape)
        print("y.shape",y.shape)
        # print("rag.shape",rag.shape)

        # x = self.reduce_x(x)
        # rag = self.reduce_rag(rag)

        # print("x.shape", x.shape)
        # print("y.shape",y.shape)
        # print("rag.shape",rag.shape)
        # z = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1), torch.unsqueeze(rag, axis=1))
        # z_rag = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1),torch.unsqueeze(rag, axis=1))
        # z_con = torch.cat((z, z_rag), dim=1)


        # Concatenate x with y and then with rag


        # z= torch.cat((torch.cat((x, y), dim=1), rag), dim=1)


        # # Pass concatenated x with y and x with rag through your network
        # z_new = torch.squeeze(z,dim=1)
        # print("z_new shape",z_new)

        z = torch.cat((x, y, rag), dim=1)
        z_new = torch.squeeze(z, dim=1)



        c_inten = self.fin_inten(z_new)
        c_e1 = self.fin_e1(z_new)
        c_e2 = self.fin_e2(z_new)
        c_e3 = self.fin_e3(z_new)
        c_e4 = self.fin_e4(z_new)
        c_e5 = self.fin_e5(z_new)
        c_e6 = self.fin_e6(z_new)
        c_e7 = self.fin_e7(z_new)
        c_e8 = self.fin_e8(z_new)
        c_e9 = self.fin_e9(z_new)
        c = self.fin_old(z_new)

        # print("z.shape",z.shape)
        # print("z_new shape",z_new.shape)
        # print("intensity error:", c_inten.shape)
        # print("output:", c.shape)
        # print("c_e1:", c_e1.shape)
        # print("c_e2:", c_e2.shape)
        # print("c_e3:", c_e3.shape)
        # print("c_e4:", c_e4.shape)
        # print("c_e5:", c_e5.shape)
        # print("c_e6:", c_e6.shape)
        # print("c_e7:", c_e7.shape)
        # print("c_e8:", c_e8.shape)
        # print("c_e9:", c_e9.shape)
        # print("logits.shape",logits.shape)


        output = torch.log_softmax(c, dim=1)
        c_inten = torch.log_softmax(c_inten, dim=1)
        c_e1 = torch.log_softmax(c_e1, dim=1)
        c_e2 = torch.log_softmax(c_e2, dim=1)
        c_e3 = torch.log_softmax(c_e3, dim=1)
        c_e4 = torch.log_softmax(c_e4, dim=1)
        c_e5 = torch.log_softmax(c_e5, dim=1)
        c_e6 = torch.log_softmax(c_e6, dim=1)
        c_e7 = torch.log_softmax(c_e7, dim=1)
        c_e8 = torch.log_softmax(c_e8, dim=1)
        c_e9 = torch.log_softmax(c_e9, dim=1)

        return output,c_inten,c_e1,c_e2,c_e3,c_e4,c_e5,c_e6,c_e7,c_e8,c_e9


    def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):

        return F.nll_loss(logits, labels)

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp= train_batch
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= train_batch
        #logit_offen,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,logit_inten_target= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        lab = train_batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = train_batch[txt]
        rag = train_batch[rag]
        img = train_batch[img]
        name= train_batch[name]
        intensity = train_batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = train_batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = train_batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = train_batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = train_batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = train_batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = train_batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = train_batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = train_batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = train_batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)

        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)
        intensity = torch.abs(intensity)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)  # Assuming you have 6 classes
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)

        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)
        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim=1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)



        logit_offen,logit_inten_target,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        loss1 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_offen, lab)
        loss17 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_inten_target, intensity)
        loss4 = self.cross_entropy_loss(a, e1)
        loss5 = self.cross_entropy_loss(b, e2)
        loss6 = self.cross_entropy_loss(c, e3)
        loss7 = self.cross_entropy_loss(d, e4)
        loss8 = self.cross_entropy_loss(e, e5)
        loss9 = self.cross_entropy_loss(f, e6)
        loss10 = self.cross_entropy_loss(g, e7)
        loss11 = self.cross_entropy_loss(h, e8)
        loss12 = self.cross_entropy_loss(i, e9)

        loss = loss1 + loss4 + loss5 + loss6 + loss7 + loss8 +loss9 + loss10 +loss11 +loss12 + loss17

        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss


    def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx):
        #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp = val_batch
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= val_batch
        lab = val_batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = val_batch[txt]
        rag = val_batch[rag]
        img = val_batch[img]
        name = val_batch[name]
        intensity = val_batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = val_batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = val_batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = val_batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = val_batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = val_batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = val_batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = val_batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = val_batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = val_batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)

        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)

        intensity = torch.abs(intensity)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)
        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)


        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim = 1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)

        logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        logits=logits.float()

        tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(),axis=1)
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
        lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
        self.log('val_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('val_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        tqdm_dict = {'val_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
        self.validation_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})

        return {
                  'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
        'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
        }

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
      outs = []
      outs14=[]
      for out in self.validation_step_outputs:
        outs.append(out['progress_bar']['val_acc'])
        outs14.append(out['val_f1 offensive'])
      self.log('val_acc_all_offn', sum(outs)/len(outs))
      self.log('val_f1 offensive', sum(outs14)/len(outs14))
      print(f'***val_acc_all_offn at epoch end {sum(outs)/len(outs)}****')
      print(f'***val_f1 offensive at epoch end {sum(outs14)/len(outs14)}****')
      self.validation_step_outputs.clear()

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= batch
        lab = batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = batch[txt]
        rag = batch[rag]
        img = batch[img]
        name = batch[name]
        intensity = batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)
        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)
        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)
        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim=1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)

        logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        logits = logits.float()
        tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(force=True),axis=-1)
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
        lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
        self.log('test_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('test_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('test_loss', loss)
        tqdm_dict = {'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
        self.test_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp), 'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})
        return {
                  'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
                  'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp),
                  'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
        }
    def on_test_epoch_end(self):
        # OPTIONAL
        outs = []
        outs1,outs2,outs3,outs4,outs5,outs6,outs7,outs8,outs9,outs10,outs11,outs12,outs13,outs14 = \
        [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
        for out in self.test_step_outputs:
          outs.append(out['test_acc'])
          outs2.append(out['test_f1_score'])
        self.log('test_acc', sum(outs)/len(outs))
        self.log('test_f1_score', sum(outs2)/len(outs2))
        self.test_step_outputs.clear()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
      # optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=3e-2)
      optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

      return optimizer


  """
  Main Model:
  Initialize
  Forward Pass
  Training Step
  Validation Step
  Testing Step

  Pp
  """

  class HmDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):

    def setup(self, stage):
      self.hm_train = t_p
      self.hm_val = v_p
      # self.hm_test = test
      self.hm_test = te_p

    def train_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_train, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_val, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

    def test_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_test, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

  data_module = HmDataModule()
  checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
      monitor='val_acc_all_offn',
      dirpath='mrinal/',
      filename='epoch{epoch:02d}-val_f1_all_offn{val_acc_all_offn:.2f}',
      auto_insert_metric_name=False,
      save_top_k=1,
      mode="max",
  )
  all_callbacks = []
  all_callbacks.append(checkpoint_callback)
  # train
  from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything
  seed_everything(42, workers=True)
  hm_model = Classifier()
  gpus=1
  #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
  trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=20,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
  trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

Here is the Full Traceback Error
INFO:lightning_fabric.utilities.seed:Seed set to 42
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:Using bfloat16 Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP)
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:GPU available: False, used: False
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary:
   | Name        | Type   | Params
----------------------------------------
0  | MFB         | MFB    | 21.0 M
1  | fin_y_shape | Linear | 393 K 
2  | fin_old     | Linear | 4.1 K 
3  | fin         | Linear | 786 K 
4  | fin_inten   | Linear | 12.3 K
5  | fin_e1      | Linear | 4.1 K 
6  | fin_e2      | Linear | 4.1 K 
7  | fin_e3      | Linear | 4.1 K 
8  | fin_e4      | Linear | 4.1 K 
9  | fin_e5      | Linear | 4.1 K 
10 | fin_e6      | Linear | 4.1 K 
11 | fin_e7      | Linear | 4.1 K 
12 | fin_e8      | Linear | 4.1 K 
13 | fin_e9      | Linear | 4.1 K 
----------------------------------------
22.2 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
22.2 M    Total params
88.951    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0%
 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
x.shape torch.Size([10, 768])
y.shape torch.Size([10, 512])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
[<ipython-input-34-4b5757f5c04a>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <cell line: 375>()
    373 #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
    374 trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=20,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
--> 375 trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

13 frames
[/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2702     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2703         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2704     return torch._C._nn.nll_loss_nd(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2705 
   2706 

RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

I am getting the error on RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported I need to solve this can Anyone help me to figure out How i can Solve this issue.

Is this the full error stack?

yes it is full error stack

Which line in your code is throwing this error?

def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
    return F.nll_loss(logits, labels)

this one

Ok but you should find out which of the 11 calls is throwing that error. Is it the first one? In that case, what are the shapes of logit_offen and lab?

why you have mention 11 calls here?

In your training loop, you are calling Classifier.cross_entropy_loss 11 times, no?

Ok I understand that, But I am a little confused , I think I have to watch Pytorch youtube tutorials to clear some concepts.
